# Processes being stopped when running a script with multiple nohup commands

Tags: linux, bash, kdb, nohup

I have created a bash script to run multiple nohup commands to start up processes, however, when the second nohup command is ran, the first process is stopped and so on. How can I fix this?

```
tp() { echo "Starting Tickerplant" ; nohup ~/q/m32/q $HomeDir"tick.q" -p $TP &> $Logs"tick.log" & }
rdb() { echo "Starting Real-Time Database" ; nohup ~/q/m32/q $FP"r.q" $TP $HDB -p $RDB &> $Logs"rdb.log" & }
fh() { echo "Starting Feedhandler" ; nohup ~/q/m32/q $FP"simpleFeed.q" &> $Logs"feed.log" & }
cep() { echo "Starting Critical Event Processer" ; nohup ~/q/m32/q $FP"cep.q" &> $Logs"cep.log" & }
```

Results in the following

```
Starting Tickerplant
[5]+  Stopped                 nohup ~/q/m32/q $HomeDir"tick.q" -p $TP >&$Logs"tick.log"
Starting Real-Time Database
[6]   Exit 1                  nohup ~/q/m32/q $FP"r.q" $TP $HDB -p $RDB >&$Logs"rdb.log"
Starting Critical Event Processer
Starting Feedhandler
FINISHED
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is a background process (kdb in this case) trying to read from a terminal. By default, only a foreground process can access a terminal; if a background process tries to do that it will be suspended. That's why you see

```
[5]+  Stopped                 nohup ~/q/m32/q $HomeDir"tick.q" -p $TP
```

the moment you press a key. You need to redirect STDIN to avoid that:

```
nohup q -p ... < /dev/null &> /path/to/log
```

Since you don't do that, when you start the RDB it can't connect to the TP (it's suspended!) and exits. That's why you see

```
[6]   Exit 1                  nohup ~/q/m32/q $FP"r.q" $TP $HDB -p $RDB
```

So make sure you detach standard input because `nohup` on macOS won't do it for you, in contrast to its GNU/Linux cousin.

Comment: Is the best way to do this through the use of < /dev/null before the log redirection?

`tp() { echo "Starting Tickerplant" ; nohup ~/q/m32/q $HomeDir"tick.q" < /dev/null  &> $Logs"tick.log" & }`

Comment: @jamesmcauley You mean `q < /dev/null > tick.log` or `q > tick.log < /dev/null`? It's up to you. While they are equivalent I persoanlly prefer the former.